# My wordpress website site URL is being changed again and again

Tags: wordpress

Someone is changing my wordpress site URL to their ad spam URL. I changed it from php my admin and it was fixed, the hacker inserted a java script to every wordpress post and pages to redirect all posts and pages to their ad page, I deleted all of them. Then I installed wordfence security plugin, scanned the entire website, found some malicious codes and deleted everything. Then I changed my cpanel and wordpress password. I am using my own VPS so I also changed my root password, but still just after 12-24 hours, I can see that the wordpress site URL has been changed. I fix it and again it becomes changed.
I have mentioned what I have done, what else I can do to prevent this? Please any suggestion will be appreciated...

Comment: Did you check the list of admin accounts? In some cases, attackers create an additional WP administrator account. Also, Wordfence must be configured to scan files "outside" of WP (to actually find malicious code in non-default locations). Additionally, you might have a plugin or theme containing a vulnerability which is hard to track down.

Comment: Yes I did checked for hidden admin, in user area, (1) is showing after Administrator like this - Administrator (1) - and that's me, so I don't think there is a hidden admin.
And yes I will check enabling outside of wordpress directory scan on wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Your website has most probably been exploited, and the exploit is still active, as a backdoor for that Hacker..

I would check the access logs for your web requests, and especially POST requests!

which might show where is the hacker logging in via.. some Theme or Plugin that was exploited most probably.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer, yes I noticed there is a plugin called ccode.php - I deleted it several times, I don't know how it appears again....
And where can I check the access logs for your web requests, and POST requests pleas? Any documentation URL will also be helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [this](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/The+cPanel+Log+Files#ThecPanelLogFiles-Apache) is the documentation. If they are recreating the `ccode.php` they are POST-ing to another file, which should be evident in your cPanel logs.

Comment: Also, in terms of securing WP, there are a lot of techniques that can be applied.

Answer (score -1):

If your web host does daily backups, it might even be worth reverting back to previous days to remove any changes... -- remember if you revert back any posts/changes from that day onwards will disappear.

Comment: That will not solve his actual problem, which will reoccur again..

Comment: How is reverting the code to yesterday's backup, fix an exploit? Exploits need to be patched with newer versions.. AND he will loose any recent posts if he reverts to an earlier date.

Comment: 1. I didnt say yesterday - I said previous days. 2. You revert back to remove the exploits / issues. 3. Patch/update. 4. I wrote a disclaimer in the answer. Leave it at that I dont want this discussion to spam his question. You have a solution which i dont disagree with and I'm providing another opinion.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, and I am the owner of my hosting as I said I am using VPS server with cPanel, and unfortunately I don't have the backup